# How to fix HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable error

Tags: bottlenose

Executing the command:

```
amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY,AMAZON_SECRET_KEY,AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId='B007OZNUCE')
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exazapi.py", line 37, in <module>
    response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId='B007OZNUCE')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 274, in __call__
    {'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 235, in _call_api
    return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

#import all the required modules
import re
import csv
import sys
import warnings
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

import bottlenose
#from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY='xxx'
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY='xxx'
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG='xxx'


#ignore warnings
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")


amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY,AMAZON_SECRET_KEY,AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId='B007OZNUCE')
print (amazon)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Region is missing, add something like "DE" or "ES" depending on the country you're using.

Default is 'US':

amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG, Region='FR')

from: https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose

Additionally: have you checked in the 'amazon' customer portal, on the 'platform API' access for the countries you want to use, that the API is enabled?

- France: https://partenaires.amazon.fr/assoc_credentials/home
- UK: https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/assoc_credentials/home
- US: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/assoc_credentials/home

For me, it shows inactive, hence, that's probably the cause for the request to be denied.

Comment: This doesnt seem to fix the issue. Ive tried adding a region but it still doesnt work. besides the keys I used were the ones from US so default should have worked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs!

The same code worked magically now. Seems the api keys weren't enabled immediately after creating them.